# Spring boot @Import for loading config integration test not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot app and i am implementing some integration test. I have 2 classes one that will hold my common configuration (Demo3ApplicationTests ) and the other one my integration test class(DumyClassTest), please find below it is empty for the time being:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Demo3Application.class)
class Demo3ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        
    }

}
```

My integration test class:

```
@Import(value = Demo3ApplicationTests.class)
public class DumyClassTest{
    
    
    
    @Autowired
    DemoService demoService;
    
    @Test
    public void testImportConfig() {
        
        demoService.logDummyMsg();
        
    }

}
```

When I run the test testImportConfig the demoService value is null as I guess the @import i am not setting it up correctly. However when I extends that is `DumyClassTest extends Demo3ApplicationTests` the demoService  is not null and the test is run correctly.

Any idea why when I use the import annotation the demoService is null?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you aren't running it with Spring but as a normal JUnit test class (which doesn't know the `@Import`.

Comment: Thnks for the quick response but the even if the import class contains @SpringBootTest(classes = Demo3Application.class) it will not be executed in spring context?

Comment: You should do a bit of research first. (at)Import is for spring configuration classes, not tests. All test classes (those with (at)Test method annotations) individually need (at)SpringBootTest. Your test in DummyTestClass is checking that spring works, not that the import has worked. You don't need to check that spring works - it has its own tests, and it does work. You should just test that your own system works. From a structure perspective, the difference between a unit and integration test is the construction of a spring context. Btw: I can't use the at sign in comments.

Comment: No, as the test needs to be annotated with `@SpringBootTest` or `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. @Import is a spring annotation so you need Spring to interpret it.